# JavaScrip 'Mouseover' not working properly. Possible JQuery not defined error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello I had gotten some help from this forum some time back. I used the suggested code and it worked great. However when I duplicate it, it does not appear to be working properly. Can someone help me diagnose what I am missing? I'm still learning JS.

There error appears to be "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

And it appears it's in here on the second line

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var parentEl = jQuery('#approach-diagram').attr('class');
jQuery('#approach-diagram span').on('mouseover', function() {
  var hoverEl = jQuery(this).attr('class');
  jQuery('#approach-diagram').attr('class', hoverEl + '-bg');
});

jQuery('#approach-diagram').on('mouseleave', function() {
  jQuery('#approach-diagram').attr('class', parentEl);
});

jQuery('#approach-diagram span').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var clickEl = jQuery(this).attr('class');
  jQuery('#approach-diagram').attr('class', clickEl + '-bg');
  jQuery('.approach-text').slideUp();
  jQuery('#' + clickEl + '-text').slideDown();
  parentEl = clickEl + '-bg';
});
    </script>
```

Here is the site where it works properly (https://wendyd58.sg-host.com/) If you scroll the the purple circle you will see how it should act.

Here is where it does not appear to be changing for anyone. https://wendyd60.sg-host.com/ It's the puzzle piece layer.

Here is the full code.

```html
<section id="approach">
    <div class="containerr">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-06 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div id="approach-diagram" class="retiremet-bg">
                <span class="retirement"></span>
                  <span class="social"></span>
                <span class="legacy"></span>
                 <span class="tax"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-006 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        
            <div id="retirement-text" class="approach-text" style="display: block" >
                <div class="cavt"> <i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="font-size: 46px;color: #d4ccb3;margin-left: -13px;"></i></div><div>  <h2>Income Planning </h2></div>
                <p>Income planning is a long-term plan for how you will manage your finances analyzing your family status, income level and financial goals.</p>  
<p style="text-align: right;"><a class="lm" href=“#”><strong>Learn More</strong></a></p>
               </div>
            <div id="social-text" class="approach-text">
                      <div class="cavt"> <i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="font-size: 46px;color: #d4ccb3;margin-left: -13px;"></i></div><div> <h2>Investment Planning</h2></div>
                <p>Knowing the risks of retirement includes understanding the risk factors as you start to withdraw from your retirement fund. </p>  
<p style="text-align: right;"><a class="lm" href=“#”><strong>Learn More</strong></a></p>
              </div>
<div id="legacy-text" class="approach-text">
                     <div class="cavt"> <i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="font-size: 46px;color: #d4ccb3;margin-left: -13px;"></i></div><div> <h2>Legacy Planning </h2></div>
                <p>Legacy planning allows people to choose how their wealth and assets are distributed once they pass away while avoiding probate process.  </p>  
<p style="text-align: right;"><a class="lm" href=“#”><strong>Learn More</strong></a></p>
              </div>
          
            <div id="tax-text" class="approach-text">
                     <div class="cavt"> <i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="font-size: 46px;color: #d4ccb3;margin-left: -13px;"></i></div><div> <h2>Tax Planning</h2></div>
                <p>Tax planning is a subset of retirement planning. This efficiency may come in the form of retaining as much of your income as possible or even reducing your tax liability so that you have as much money as possible during your retirement.</p>  
<p style="text-align: right;"><a class="lm" href=“#”><strong>Learn More</strong></a></p>
</div>

              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var parentEl = jQuery('#approach-diagram').attr('class');
jQuery('#approach-diagram span').on('mouseover', function() {
  var hoverEl = jQuery(this).attr('class');
  jQuery('#approach-diagram').attr('class', hoverEl + '-bg');
});

jQuery('#approach-diagram').on('mouseleave', function() {
  jQuery('#approach-diagram').attr('class', parentEl);
});

jQuery('#approach-diagram span').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var clickEl = jQuery(this).attr('class');
  jQuery('#approach-diagram').attr('class', clickEl + '-bg');
  jQuery('.approach-text').slideUp();
  jQuery('#' + clickEl + '-text').slideDown();
  parentEl = clickEl + '-bg';
});
    </script>
</section>
```

Any help would be apprecaited!

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting the jquery library? In head?

Comment: Include the JQuery library in your html and try again.
```<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import jQuery before the script:

```
<!-- This line here -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var parentEl = jQuery('#approach-diagram').attr('class');
jQuery('#approach-diagram span').on('mouseover', function() {
  var hoverEl = jQuery(this).attr('class');
  jQuery('#approach-diagram').attr('class', hoverEl + '-bg');
});
...
...
...
```

Comment: This is why I love StackOverflow. You're right and IDK how I missed that. Thanks so much!